# Single-spa in iframe - Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:9000" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: reactjs, iframe, single-spa

I'm just saying that this is not the problem [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame). **I use single-spa** and I was given the task to add one of the single-spa projects to a **regular** **react** project using iframe, I don't need to pass any data, just display it. But after I add the single-spa project in an iframe on another project (domains are different) I get the following error. The first thing that came to my mind is that the problem is in the **Content-Security-Policy**, it goes to the root-config in the index. jsx `-<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https: localhost:*; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: localhost: *; connect-src https: localhost:* ws://localhost:*; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:; object-src 'none';worker-src 'self' blob:">`, found - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors, but I don't understand how to pass it to this project to make it work, I tried it through webpack, it doesn't work. I would be VERY grateful to anyone who can help me figure it out.
[image]

Comment: were you able to solve it? i'm running into the same problem?